# Minimise SQLite close() calls

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlcipher

### Intro

I  am using the library, [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) in my Android project, which allows me to access a pre-encrypted SQLite v3 database from within my application.

The only downside is that there is currently a lot of overhead when creating a new database connection (`getReadableDatabase()` and `getWritableDatabase()`calls), due to all the encryption stuff that goes on every time the database is opened. These calls are currently slowing down my application significantly.

### What I am trying to achieve

So, I am seeking to minimise the number of times that I needs to make these calls, by holding a single active connection to my database across all of my activities.

### How I intend to achieve this

1. Instantiate connection to database upon application start
2. For each activity, maintain a special flag
3. Whenever an activity is switched to another (via an intent), this boolean flag is set **true**
4. Each activity's `onDestroy()` method will close the application's connection to the database, unless that activity's flag is **true** (i.e., application isn't being destroyed, we are simply moving to a different activity)

### An example

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    // Used to determine whether we are destroying the activity due to an intent.
    private boolean isIntent = false;

    public void someMethod() {
        isIntent = true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeOtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (!isIntent)
            // We haven't started another activity, so we should close the open
            // database connection.
            DatabaseHelper.close();
    }

}
```

### Questions

1. Are there any issues to this approach that I haven't considered? I haven't seen it done before, so I am wary.
2. Is there a better way of achieving the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton class around your subclass of the SQLCipher-based `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Within the `SQLiteOpenHelper`, calls to `getWritableDatabase()` internally cache the returned database object, so key derivation is not occurring each time that method is called.

Comment: Can you please expand on this answer?

Comment: The first time `getWritableDatabase(…)` is called with a non-null key value, key derivation occurs, however the database instance is cached internally (see [here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/blob/master/src/net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#L132)) so as long as you maintain a singleton of your subclassed `SQLiteOpenHelper` you will minimize the delay in accessing your data.